# How to add whitespace between elements when printing them out in Smalltalk OrderedCollection?

Tags: smalltalk

I have created an OrderedCollection list an now I want to print it out by using the Transcript, like this:

```
  range do:[:each|Transcript show: each].
```

The output is 35791113, but I need 3 5 7 9 11 13, so I need whitespaces between elements.
I tryed also just..

```
   Transcript show: range.
```

But instead of this OrderedCollection(3 5 7 9 11 13), I would like to have only list elements, without OrderedCollection.
How to achieve this?

Comment: What dialect are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Squeak, Pharo and Cuis you may do

```
 #(3 5 7 9 11 13) do: [:each | Transcript show: each; space]
```

to get the result.

Comment: This approach appends a space even for the last element. Smalltalk has the nice (and mentioned in other answers) method #do:separatedBy: that omits the trailing one.

Answer (score 7):

In **Pharo** you could simply do

```
Transcript show: (range joinUsing: ' ')
```

or the opposite

```
Transcript show: (' ' join: range)
```

This will work even if the elements are numbers.

In **GNU Smalltalk** you need to be more explicit

```
Transcript show: ((range collect: [ :each | each asString ]) join: ' ')
```

Finally you could simply expand what you've already tried with `do:separatedBy:`

```
range
    do: [ :each | Transcript show: each ]
    separatedBy: [ Transcript show: ' ' ]
```

Comment: You should do `[:each | Transcript show: each printString ]` in case the elements are not printable.

Comment: @emaringolo how can be an Object not printable (except for error ofc)? Also `Transcript` will call `#asString` automatically (at least in Pharo). So I suppose the question is whether we want `#asString` or `#printString`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `#asString` send by `Transcript`. I just looked it and it delegates the message to `#print: aString`. So you're right.

Answer (score 4):

A dialect-independent solution would look like

```
| first |
first := true.
range do: [:each |
    first ifTrue: [frist := false] ifFalse: [Transcript show: ' '].
    Transcript show: each]
```

However, every dialect has already a way to do this. For example, in Pharo we have the `#do:separatedBy:` message:

```
range do: [:each | Transcript show: each] separatedBy: [Transcript show: ' ']
```

The other thing you might want to do is to use `Transcript space` to get

```
range do: [:each | Transcript show: each] separatedBy: [Transcript space]
```

Also, I would recommend a more general approach where you dump your string representation on a more general kind of object such as a `WriteStream`:

```
dump: range on: aStream
    range do: [:each | each printOn: aStream] separatedBye: [aStream space]
```

so now you can simply write

```
<receiver> dump: range on: Transcript
```

to get the desired result.